# I try use my local js file to get remote ip data,but it not works

Tags: javascript, java

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    //按钮单击时执行
    alert("begin....");
    $("#testAjax").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://XXXXXXX:8080/iswustserver/iswust/user/queryUserList",
           data: {"page_num":"1"},
           dataType:"json",  
           contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8',
           success: function (data) { alert("1") },  
           error: function (data) { console.log(data)}
        });
     });
});
```

My Server:

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
      }
```

i use my local js file to request remote ip to get data ,but it return 400
bad request....

Answer (score 0):

I know this might sound funny and if it works hoorah if it doesn't then we will look in an alternative:

try changing your type to method e.g.

```
 $.ajax({
           method: "POST", // <--change here
           url: "http://XXXXXXX:8080/iswustserver/iswust/user/queryUserList",
           data: {"page_num":"1"},
           dataType:"json",  
           contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8',
           success: function (data) { alert("1") },  
           error: function (data) { console.log(data)}
        });
```

Comment: Can you maybe add the code of the method you are posting the data to ? Is it an api ? Is there some sort of config URI ?